# Web service REST : How to pass URL in parameter?

Tags: .net, rest, wcf, url, parameters

I have a WCF REST web service:

IService.vb :

```
<OperationContract()>
<WebInvoke(Method:="Get", 
      UriTemplate:=:GetFileList/{DirectoryName},
      RequestFormat:=...Json
      ResponseFormat:=...Json
      BodyStyle:=...Wrapped)>
Function GetFileList(ByVal DirectoryName as String) As ArrayList()
```

Service.svc.vb :

```
Public Function GetFileList(ByVal DirectoryName as String) As ArrayList() Implements IService.GetFileList
    Return "------ " & DirectoryName & " ---------"
End Function
```

and I have to pass in parameter a URL, for example

```
DirectoryName = "C: \ Programs"
```

**localhost:49658/Service.svc/GetFileList/C:\Programs**

At first it generated me an error “A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)” so in the web.config file I added :

```
<pages validateRequest="false" />             - it gave nothing
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />     - it gave nothing
```

and :

```
<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,%,&amp;,? />
```

and it lets me write ":". But now, it don't work, I have an error : "Endpoint not found" which is normal because I'm using "\"

So, know you how to pass this url address in parameter? I heard about the encoding but I do not understand how it works and each time I go to set another URL (path of directory).

Thanks,
Ela

Comment: You have thought of Encoding the URL and then pass ?? Encoding will treat your URL as string and you can decode it at server end and use for whatever logic you want . Base64 Encoding can be used in this scenario.

Comment: Super, thanks, it works :)